# Add ABMultiValue Cell in UITableView with coredata

Tags: uitableview, core-data, addressbook, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have sync the ABRecordID and person's name in core data but without syncing the mobile & email.

Then I create a UITableView using NSFetchedResultsController, predicating the contact name. One person to one cell in UITableView.

The question here, i just want to add extra cells appending to the specific contact cell showing their multi-value mobiles & emails (one value in one cell), with out storing the data to core data.

I know i can get there if i sync mobiles and emails to contact-related entities. But how can i achieve that without storing those data?

Many thanks.
Superk

Answer (score 0):

How about this: I attach another entity (for example, mobile) to each contact with one-to-many relationship. then when fetching the target contact, i get its value through addressbook and set the value of the mobile entity but without saving the context.

i guess it's ok but don't know any way to improve the performance.